# video play not support in magento

Tags: php, magento

I have try to add youtube video on my page but its give error mime type can you please help me to resole this

```
<div class="footer-inner-outer contact-dlc">
  <video width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
  <source src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/EPeLTYFlgv0" type="video/webm" />  
  Your browser does not support the video tag. 
  </video>
</div>
```

Comment: Just your browser does not support video/webm

Comment: Try adding `<source src="youtubelink" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="youtubelink" type="video/ogg">`

Comment: so how to solved this any another way to add video on my php page in magento?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```html
<div class="footer-inner-outer contact-dlc">
  <iframe width="320" height="240" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/EPeLTYFlgv0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: this also cannot play, have you test it.